# How to invoke my own implementation of `tan` function, rather than the one defined in math.h?

Tags: c, linker

I try to invoke my own implementation of `tan` function, but my gcc only invokes the one defined in math.h (i.e,  libm.a's ). Suppose I have main.c that invokes `tan`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

double tan(double);

main(){
printf ("Hello, %g\n ", tan(1.0));

}
```

and my `foo.c` which implements `tan`

```
double tan(double x){
   return 1000.9999;
}
```

Then I link the two, expecting 1000.9999 as output

```
gcc main.c foo.c; ./a.out
```

But I get:

```
Hello, 1.55741
```

where 1.55741 should be tan(1) calculated by the one of math.h, rather than by the one defined in  `foo.c`. How can I link main.c and foo.c in such a way that the 'tan' in foo.c is  invoked? (Here, I do not intend to change 'tan' to another name.)

[Edit] Regarding my compiler: I am using gcc version 4.8.2 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1)

Comment: Can you please explain why you want that? Also, this shouldn't happen because you are not linking to `libm.so` anyway! This "*Here, I do not intend to change 'tan' to another name.*" is there any **good** reason?

Comment: @ihrob, Sometimes, you may want to implement your own math function, rather than using the one provided by your system.

Comment: Ok, but why not change it's name. It's wise to use a name like `my_own_tan_implementation()`.

Comment: @ihrab, No. In thiis question, I need to find a way to call a user-defined function that happens to have the same name as the library function. This user-defined functon is not written by myself, so not easy to change.

Comment: @iharob. As specified in the post, the linking is done via "gcc main.c foo.c; ./a.out".

Comment: Where is the user defined function defined then?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103547/discussion-between-zell-and-iharob).

Comment: In Standard C, defining your own functions with the same name as library functions causes undefined behaviour.   To persist with this approach will mean relying on particular behaviour of your compiler or linker;  so your question should include details of which compiler and linker you are using, and which version.

Comment: @M.M Please read [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35420892/how-to-invoke-my-own-implementation-of-tan-function-rather-than-the-one-defin?noredirect=1#comment58542440_35420892). I think this is a valid reason.

Comment: @iharob to avoid making rotten code, changing the other function is still the preferred solution .  (Perhaps this could be done by applying preprocessing to the other function's source and headers, to avoid editing the other source at least)

Comment: @M.M Of course! If one had access to the source code, that wasn't clarified by the OP

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass `-fno-builtin` to the compiler invocation. By default, gcc uses an optimization where standard library functions are replaced with special instructions under the expectation that they do what they should do.

To turn off that optimization, pass `-fno-builtin` to turn it off for all functions or `-fno-builtin-function` to turn it off just for `function`, e.g. `-fno-builtin-tan` to turn off the optimization for the `tan` function.

Depending on your platform, you might also need to not include `<math.h>`. That header might contain a macro named `tan` or an inline definition, which might cause the problems you observe.

Comment: Well this is the solution. I was very surprised that even though I didn't link to *libm.so* it still used the library function. But it didn't complain about linking to *libm.so* like it normally does because I provided my own definition of `tan()`. This behavior is very misleading.

Comment: `#undef tan` would be a way to deal with the second problem

Comment: @iharob Standard library functions are conventionally made weak symbols so you can override them with your own. Thus, no warning. This behaviour is important so programs don't suddenly stop working or compiling when the libc introduces a new symbol used internally by your program.

Comment: It works!! Thanks so much.

Comment: Changing tan(1.0) into tan(1.0 + argc) as well as adding the arguments for main(int argc, char* argv []) actually calls the posters custom version of tan.

Gcc actually replaced the call to tan(1.0) already at compile time by a constant (even at lowest optimization level O0), so when it was time to link, the original version of tan was not  used anymore, and the posters custom version which could scilently override it was never needed.